# Always a 'Network error' on mobile in Ubuntu One Music

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I'm using Ubuntu One in Android 2.3. I have always a "A network error occured. Try again later" when I try to retrieve the list of music files on cloud (the demo goes well). My network connection is Ok (Wi-fi and 3G).

Is this some server problem or something that I can resolve?

Specs:

- Android 2.3.3 on LG-P500h
- Ubuntu One Music, version 1.5

Answer (score 1):

We've released an update of Ubuntu One Music. Please upgrade. If you're still experiencing the issue, please contact us at ubuntuone-support at canonical.com

Thanks!